# Unmarshall an XML file and save to database in Java

Tags: java, spring, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following XML file being uploaded in Java to unmarshall:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MyValues>
    <Type Value="ABC">
        <CustomerName>Sample</CustomerName>
        <EmailAddress>sample@abcd.com</EmailAddress>
        <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
        <HardwareKey>abc-def-123-456</HardwareKey>
    </Type>
</MyValues>
```

I want to upload this file's values to my database in my Spring Application. The Java code to unmarshall is:

```
String transformedFileName = TRANSFORMED_FILE_DIRECTORY+"/"+fileName;

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerDetails.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

        customerDetails = (CustomerDetails) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(transformedFileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        
        System.out.println(customerDetails);
```

and the CustomerDetails.java is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customerDetails")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class CustomerDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String type;
    
    private String hardwareKey;
    
    private String emailAddress;
    
    private Long phoneNumber;
    
    private String customerName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getHardwareKey() {
        return hardwareKey;
    }

    public void setHardwareKey(String hardwareKey) {
        this.hardwareKey = hardwareKey;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Long getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(Long phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting while running this:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"MyValues"). Expected elements are (none)
```

I cannot change the file values and structure, and have to save the file values in database. How to overcome this error and how to save the values? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it will be impossible to use the same class for both ORM and JAXB purposes.

I would suggest to read the XML file with JDOM or a similar library and manually map the xml elements to CustomerDetail objects. Something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

public class XmlParsing {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document document = new SAXBuilder().build(new File("test.xml"));
    for(Element typeElement : document.getRootElement().getChildren("Type")) {
      CustomerDetails customerDetails = new CustomerDetails();
      customerDetails.setType(typeElement.getAttributeValue("Value"));
      customerDetails.setCustomerName(typeElement.getChildText("CustomerName"));
      // etc.
      // save customerDetails to database
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is now working..if I do a  customerDetails.getCustomerName(), I get Null Pointer Exception, even when setting the customer name.

Comment: Seems to be unrelated to the question asked here. Ask a new question, and provide more information.

Comment: The error is: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.service.FileService.storeFile(FileService.java:62) ~[classes/:na]                                                                                                                 The line 62 is: customerDetails.setCustomerName(typeElement.getChildText("CustomerName"));          And the imports are:                                                                                                            import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything works so far and the xml format fixed (and xml size is small).

(It *is* quite possible/handy/convenient to mix [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) with [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb) annotations, BUT the structure of xml and database should match.)

In this case (the structural difference is too complex/xml adjustment is not an option,) we should:

1. Generate jaxb class(es  `MyValues`) from the (fixed, rarely updated) xml/xsd.
   ("by hand", or with some tools: https://www.google.com/search?q=jaxb+generate+classes+from+xml, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14252/adx_j_jaxb.htm, https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb) ...until the `unmarshall()`, produces desirable results (tests!).
2. Check this/ese class(es) into source control, and maintain only/whenever XML changes.
3. Use this generated class(es), to (find&update existing or?) create `new` `CustomerDetails`... like:

   ```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyValues.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

    MyValues myValues = (MyValues) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(transformedFileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    // get a new db id:
    CustomerDetails customerDetails = new CustomerDetails(); 

    // ... or search for existing... !? (myValues.getEmail()!?;)

    // if you want to learn about "object mappers", just do it, otherwise, you have to "manually"...:
    customerDetails.setXXX(myValues.getXXX()); // ...

   // and finally do something with customerDetails... 
   // like: repository.save(custpomerDetails);  
   // and: LOGGER.debug("customer saved: {}", customerDetails.getId());
   ```

---

BUT, the xml element name `MyValues` **suggests**, that the xml is "under construction", so please also try to adjust it to the "desired":

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!-- name space ?? -->
 <CutomerDetails>
    <type>some type</type>
    <hardwareKey>someHardwareKey</hardwareKey>
    <emailAddress>john.doe@sample.com</emailAddress>
    <phoneNumber>+12345678901</phoneNumber>
    <customerName>John Doe</customerName>
</CustomerDetails>
```

... then adding `@XmlRootElement` (above `CustomerDetails` class)  and "ignoring the `id`" by adding `@XmlTransient` (to `public void setId()` ...), *could* make your original code working.

Comment: I get the XML fom client. If I cannot make changes to it, in that case how to achieve the output then?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jaxb+generate+classes+from+xml, @KaranSaxena (step 1.;)